# Add Blank Line to Word Output RMarkdown

Tags: ms-word, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, blank-line

Good day.

I am trying to create a conference abstract submission using a rmarkdown file which exports to a word document. I am trying to find a way to insert a blank line in the outputted word document. I have found that a line break can be inserted by adding two blank spaces at the end of a markdown file, however, this trick does not work when you simply want a blank line. Below is example code

````
  ---
title: "HERE IS THE TITLE OF MY ABSTRACT"
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: draft-styles.docx
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library(rmarkdown)
```


Authors: John H. Curry^1^, Kathy S. James^1^, Patrick S. Curry^1^
Affiliations: ^1^University of Somewhere 

*Presenting author information*  
Name: John H. Curry 
Email: curry@umed.edu  
Affiliation details: Kinesiology, University of Somewhere, Ottawa, Canada  


*Coauthor #2*  
Name: Kathy S. James  
Email: james@umed.edu 
Affiliation details: Kinesiology, University of Somewhere, Ottawa, Canada  

*Coauthor #3*  
Name: Patrick S. Curry 
Email: curry2@umed.edu  
Affiliation details: Kinesiology, University of Somewhere, Ottawa, Canada  


## Introduction
Here is where I write my introduction....

## Methods
Here is where I write my methods

## Results
Here is where I write my results...

## Discussion
Here is where I write my discussion
````

When I knit the document, sadly its a little clustered. Below I've added a picture with the current output (left) and what I would like it to look like (right). 
[image: img]

I have read through forums and I have yet to see a solution for this when using a word document. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can use `\newline` in the Rmd file as follows:

````
---
title: "HERE IS THE TITLE OF MY ABSTRACT"
output:
  word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library(rmarkdown)
```


Authors: John H. Curry^1^, Kathy S. James^1^, Patrick S. Curry^1^
    Affiliations: ^1^University of Somewhere

\newline

*Presenting author information*
    Name: John H. Curry
Email: curry@umed.edu
Affiliation details: Kinesiology, University of Somewhere, Ottawa, Canada

\newline

*Coauthor #2*
Name: Kathy S. James
Email: james@umed.edu
Affiliation details: Kinesiology, University of Somewhere, Ottawa, Canada

\newline

*Coauthor #3*
Name: Patrick S. Curry
Email: curry2@umed.edu
Affiliation details: Kinesiology, University of Somewhere, Ottawa, Canada

\newline

## Introduction
Here is where I write my introduction....

\newline

## Methods
Here is where I write my methods

\newline

## Results
Here is where I write my results...

\newline

## Discussion
Here is where I write my discussion
````

In case you are going to ask next, newpage is slightly harder. You will need to create a new style in word for Heading 5 (for e.g.) which auto starts on a new page and in your Rmd file you will use heading 5 as your new line. there are quite a number of resources online regarding this though.

Comment: This is perfect! I was able to get my desired output using a combination of \newline and adding double spaces at the end of lines. For those interested I posted the code that gave me the results I was seeking

Comment: This no longer works for me, however the answer below from @eric krantz worked (<br>) https://stackoverflow.com/a/63156393/603776

Answer (score 28):

I upvoted the answer 2 years ago, but now `\newline` doesn't work for me. However, `<br>` works. Make sure you have empty space above and below `<br>`. Works for charts and code snippet output too.

```
    ---
title: "Word/knitr linefeed test"
author: "E Krantz"
date: "7/28/2020"
output: word_document
---

Here are results with no assisted new line.

How to new line in knitr with MSWord? Test newline:

\newline  \newline

That doesn't work. Test br:
<br>
That does not work. Test br with linebreak after:
<br>

No changes. Test br with linebreak before:

<br>
This puts a space before this sentence. Test br with break before and after.

<br>

That works! Double br:

<br>
<br>

Same as single br. How about double br with a line break between each?

<br>

<br>

That works!
```

Here are the results:
[image: Results]

Comment: this solution works !! thanks for writing this answer you saved me

Comment: It works - and thank you for including the detail about space before and after - that would have been easy to miss.but geez! It seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 10):

An answer was provided to me by chinsoon12. Here is the code I used to get the desired output. I do find it a little bit strange that I needed to write \newline \newline (rather than putting it only once). It was also not possible to add \newline at the end of a line of code and get the same effect. You need to have a line breaks in your .rmd file in order for it to work (at least from what I attempted).

````
---
title: "HERE IS THE TITLE OF MY ABSTRACT"
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: draft-styles.docx
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library(rmarkdown)
```


Authors: John H. Curry^1^, Kathy S. James^1^, Patrick S. Curry^1^ 

\newline

Affiliations: ^1^University of Michigan  

\newline  \newline

*Presenting author information*  
Name: John H. Curry  
Email: curry@umed.edu  
Affiliation details: Kinesiology, University of Somewhere, Ottawa, Canada  

\newline \newline

*Coauthor #2*  
Name: Kathy S. James  
Email: james@umed.edu   
Affiliation details: Kinesiology, University of Somewhere, Ottawa, Canada  

\newline \newline

*Coauthor #3*  
Name: Patrick S. Curry  
Email: curry2@umed.edu  
Affiliation details: Kinesiology, University of Somewhere, Ottawa, Canada  

\newline \newline

## Introduction
Here is where I write my introduction....

\newline \newline

## Methods
Here is where I write my methods

\newline \newline


## Results
Here is where I write my results...

\newline \newline

## Discussion
Here is where I write my discussion

\newline \newline
````